# spring data jpa repository inject fails using @Autowired in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**spring boot entry class**

```
package com.test;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude={
DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class})
public class AssetManagementDigital2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AssetManagementDigital2Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Controller class**

```
package com.test.assetmanagementdigital.controller;

 @RestController

public class ShopController {

    @Autowired
    private ShopServiceImpl shopServiceImpl;

    @RequestMapping(value="/shops",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void shopDetails(Shop shop){
        shopServiceImpl.addShopDetails(shop);

    }

}
```

**Entity**

```
package com.test.assetmanagementdigital.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="ShopDetails")
public class Shop {

    private String shopName;
    private Address address;

    public String getShopName() {
        return shopName;
    }

    public void setShopName(String shopName) {
        this.shopName = shopName;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }


}
```

**data jpa repository interface**

```
package com.test.assetmanagementdigital.repository;
    @Repository
    public interface ShopRepository extends CrudRepository<Shop,Long>{

    }
```

**Service class**

```
package com.test.assetmanagementdigital.service;
@Service
public class ShopServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    private ShopRepository shopRepository;

    public void addShopDetails(Shop shop) {
        shopRepository.save(shop);
    }

}
```

**gradle file**

```
 buildscript {
        ext {
            springBootVersion = '2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
        }
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
            maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'war'

    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }

    configurations {
        providedRuntime
    }

    dependencies {
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
        compile("com.h2database:h2")
        compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '4.2.2.Final'
        providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
        testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    }
```

I am getting following error

```
Description:

Field shopRepository in com.test.assetmanagementdigital.service.ShopServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.test.assetmanagementdigital.repository.ShopRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.test.assetmanagementdigital.repository.ShopRepository' in your configuration.
```

if i remove the `@Autowired` annotation from `ShopRepository` then it will throw `NullPointerException

I have tried `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.test.assetmanagementdigital.repository")` here I get

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'shopController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'shopServiceImpl'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'shopServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'shopRepository'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shopRepository': Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType;
```

Comment: I believe `@Transactional` annotation missing

Comment: Your dependencies are wrong (this is what the last stacktrace / error is telling you). Add your pom file or gradle file.

Comment: gradle file added

Comment: Remove the `hibernate-core` dependency that is already added through `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. The version you add is an older version as ncluded in the starter leading to conflicting versions. Easy solution, as stated, remove the `hibernate-core` dependency.

Comment: that's true removing hibernate-core dependency above error gone but comes new one

Comment: thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Spring configuration is not correct.

The `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` already provides the `hibernate-core` dependency. While you declare it with a specific version :

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '4.2.2.Final'
```

You have not to declare it a second time as your specified version may be different and not compatible with the version provided by the starter.

And according to your error, it seems be the case as the `javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()` method is not found at runtime.

> Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is
>   `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`:
>   `javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType`;

Just remove the `hibernate-core` dependency and it should work.

Comment: You don't need `@EnableJpaRepositories` in a spring boot application. Spring Boot automatically detects Spring Data JPA (and others) and configures the appropriate `@Enable*Repositories` for it.

Comment: @M. Deinum you are totally right. I modified my answer. Thank you to ensure good quality content.

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide the package name to Spring to scan the repositories from, using `@EnableJpaRepositories` annnotation, e.g.:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.test.assetmanagementdigital.repository")
public class AssetManagementDigital2Application
```

[Here's](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) the documentation.

Comment: I have edit question above please check n also tried this before

Comment: You don't need `@EnableJpaRepositories` in a spring boot application. Spring Boot automatically detects Spring Data JPA (and others) and configures the appropriate `@Enable*Repositories` for it.

Comment: @kiranrathod is there any reason why `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` is disabled?