# Why Getting error "Error creating bean with name '***': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field '***'"

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am getting  the errors while building the application using maven as below:

## Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '***Controller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field '***ServiceImpl'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '***ServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field '***Repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '***Repository': Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType;
```

find the classes as below:

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;


    ------
}
```

Service Class:

```
@Service
public interface UserService {

    ----
}
```

Service impl class:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    ------

}
```

Repository class:

```
@Repository
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String>{

        @Query(value = "SELECT Number FROM User where Token = :token", nativeQuery=true)
        public String findNumber(@Param("token") String token);


    }
```

Entity class:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @XmlElement(name = "Number")
    protected String number;
    @XmlElement(name = "Token", required = true)
    protected String token;

    //setter & getters

}
```

Can anyone please suggest on this.

Comment: Based on the NoSuchMethodError: javax.persitence.PersistenceContext.synchronization it seems you have a problem with JPA dependencies (i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44413819/1570834). What does your pom look like?

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**
Remove @service from Interface and
 autowired Interface in your controller class
**Like this**

```
 public interface UserService 
{ 
}

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService
{
      @Autowired
       private UserRepository userRepository;
}

@Controller
public class UserController
{
   @Autowired
   private UserService service //autowired interface
}
```

**Solution 2**

Try removing @service from ServiceImpl class and Autowired interface in controller class like above

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding `ContextLoaderListener` in your `web.xml`.

```
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

it looks like the failure is occuring during dispatcher initialization and the corresponding DAO dependency injection.

Comment: I am using maven with springboot project so there is no web.xml in springboot project

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your repository bean is not getting created because of some method (probably `findNumber`). As a result of this, there are unsatisfied dependencies in respected service and controller classes.

Your exception message says it all:  `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:` in your repo class