# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsService'

Tags: java, spring

I've seen this mistake lots of times already, but I just cannot repair it. Full stack trace:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'usersRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usersRepository': Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1348) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at com.example.springinfobip.SpringinfobipApplication.main(SpringinfobipApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usersRepository': Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType;
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.<init>(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:653) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.lambda$buildPersistenceMetadata$1(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:435) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:522) ~[spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:420) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:394) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:332) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1020) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

I am new to spring so I have no idea what I am doing, I was following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=egXtoL5Kg08) in which I want to make authentication from H2 (only database is different, but that shouldn't make problems)
My code is:

CustomerUserDetailsService.java:

```
package com.example.springinfobip;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository usersRepository;


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<Users> optionalUsers = usersRepository.findByName(username);

        optionalUsers
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found"));
        return optionalUsers
                .map(CustomUserDetails::new).get();
    }
}
```

UsersRepository:

```
package com.example.springinfobip;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Optional;
@Service
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer> {
    Optional<Users> findByName(String username);
}
```

SecurityConfiguration

```
 package com.example.springinfobip;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Override
    protected  void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}
```

CustomerUserDetails

```
package com.example.springinfobip;

import com.example.springinfobip.Users;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Collection;

public class CustomUserDetails extends Users implements UserDetails {

    public CustomUserDetails(final Users entity) {
        super(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return super.getPassword();

    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return super.getAccId();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>springinfobip</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>springinfobip</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

my application.properties:

```
# H2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
# Datasource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test

spring.datasource.username=sa

spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

and my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit">
        <class>com.example.springinfobip.Users</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="toplink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:file:~/test"/>
            <property name="toplink.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:file:~/test"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:h2:file:~/test"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:file:~/test"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: could you try `CrudRepository` instead of `JpaRepository`?

Comment: are you sure that you have added all neccesary dependencies ?

Comment: @dehasi I edited pom.xml in my question. I don't think there are any more dependencies i need to add

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence may be useful

Comment: same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/44413819/995891 I guess - do not add an outdated hibernate-core dependency yourself, spring-boot-starter-data-jpa brings one that matches. Same applies to most of your dependencies. You're more or less not supposed to specify them yourself when you use spring boot, you specify just the boot packages for jpa, security, ... compare your pom to the one in https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/ for example

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think all code is good but in your repository, you should not use @Service, instead of it you can use @Repository annotation and use
 CrudRepository instead of JpaRepository.

one more point is that you are not following naming conventions like instead of CustomUserDetailsService I would suggest you `UserDetailsServiceImpl` because you implementing the UserDetailsService interface.

Comment: It's still not working, do you think there are some dependencies missing or what?

Comment: The spring-boot-starter-data-jpa already provides the hibernate-core dependency.

Comment: Just remove the hibernate-core dependency and it should work.

Comment: Still nothing, now I get `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;`
Is that connected to persistence.xml maybe? Or application.properties?

Comment: can you share you application.yml ?

Comment: check you db name and other info

Comment: I shared what I have in my project more or less. I had database connection before I tried to implement authentication. I am pretty sure that the tables and db name are correct because otherwise I would get error from IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this exception by replacing the corrupted jar files.

But to find those corrupted jar files, I have to run my application in three 3 IDE- 1) Intellij Idea 2)NetBeans 3) Eclipse.

Netbeans given me information for maximum number of corrupted jar. In Netbeans along with the run, I use the build option(after right clicking on project) to know more about corrupted jars.

It took me more than 15 hours to find out the root cause for these errors. Hope it help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Change the version of your spring in the file pom.xml to 2.1.0.RELEASE, or another version.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```