# Spring Boot - Error creating bean with name (JPA implementation conflict)

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

The situation is as follows. Spring Boot application. There is pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.pr.hotels</groupId>
        <artifactId>hotels</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>api-consumer</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>api-consumer</name>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.prime</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>booking</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Add Maven coordinates (GAV) for: maven-war-plugin -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Everything works fine on the local machine. But when porting to the server, an error occurs when starting:

```
 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/booking##7927]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1795)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataGrubber': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'lastChangeService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'lastChangeServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'lastChangeRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lastChangeRepository': Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586)
...
```

Finding the root of the problem led me to the possibility that there are too many versions of the jpa implementation in the assembled WAR. And it happened. In / WEB-INF / lib / I found many libraries that are somehow related to jpa. Here they are:

- hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.2.Final.jar
- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar
- spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar

Here is a screenshot with a complete list of libraries:

[image]

The project took from another person and I can not say how it happened, because in `pom` I did not notice anything superfluous. I can not understand how now to leave only what you need and throw away all the superfluous and the most important question is that there is too much of jpa that can conflict?

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType;` Shows incompatible jar files. Can you show the complete stacktrace?

Comment: you need to have a JPA PROVIDER in the classpath and you're not showing one

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186063/spring-boot-error-creating-bean-with-name  so suggest that you close one of them

Comment: @BillyFrost What do you mean by saying JPA PROVIDER? Is this particular lib? if it so what is the lib? I think I have too many libs already.

Comment: JPA implementation, JPA provider. Hibernate? EclipseLink? DataNucleus? something?

Comment: @BillyFrost Don't `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar` or `spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar` contain JPA provider?

Comment: Why would they? They are a layer ON TOP OF the JPA API. They are supposed to be usable with ANY JPA provider

Comment: @BillyFrost You can see hibernate in classpath

Comment: Nope. "hibernate-commons-annotations" is annotations. hibernate-jpa-api is the JPA API (not the implementation). "hibernate-validator" is a Bean Validation API implementation.

Comment: @BillyFrost  I can't understand why does it work then on the local machine and doesn't on server with the same libs in /WEB-INF/lib/ ?  And about implementation JPA I've found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44413819/1912193